# How to integrate timepicker plugin with datepicker in yii? Can anyone illustrate it step by step?

Tags: php, yii-extensions

I have Downloaded all source file from http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ but dont know where to put this code in file structure of yii.can any one help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension already made for this. For easy use try the following link :-

[DateTime Picker Yii Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/timepicker/)

And this extension is based on the link you gave in the question.

Comment: I am getting this error when using timepicker: Alias "widgets.timepicker.timepicker" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.     --All my file having read write permissions.

Comment: Where are you putting the downloaded files?

Comment: in localhost /myapp/protected/extensions/

Comment: Try this @DDsYii

$this->widget('application.extensions.timepicker.timepicker', array(...));